# No modules in Python 3.5.2

Tags: module

I've just installed Python 3.5.2 and I'm currently using Pycharm, when I go to settings to check the modules it has installed there is no modules at all (while python 2.7 has some modules installed). Why is this? I installed it in other PC very long ago and it had many modules by defult. Is there any way to fix this? I think I installed it properly so I don't know why this is happening.

Also when I execute `python3` it says the command wasn't found (I don't know if this has something to do), I have to use python3.5 instead.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Which modules are you trying to import?

Comment: You can provide a `python3` alias or symbolic link (dependent on your OS) to the `python3.5` executable if you want.